# Make a section of page intact on postback

Tags: java, php, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I was curious how FB http://www.facebook.com/ makes the chat window intact (fixed where it is ) even if you click any link on that page behind the chat. The URL changes, page's content get changed but the Chat window remains intact. Can you put some light how can I implement that feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is that it's not using postback. There's only ever one 'page' loaded, but content, layout, URL and the like are all being updated client side via AJAX requests. It remains one persistent page as far as the browser is concerned. emusic.com recently implemented a site in a similar vein.